# After upgrading to windows 10 can't connect to SQL Server\ tfs remotely

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, vpn

Recently upgraded my laptop to Windows 10. After upgrading i am unable to connect to either SQL Server or tfs when i'm using VPN. so let me describe the flow.

1. connecting to office over checkpoint secure remote: version vpn E80.51 build 986000202.
2. open SQL Server management studio 2014 and getting ERROR 26.[image: SQL Error]
3. open Visual studio 2017 and try to connect to our tfs. [image: TFS Error]

i know for fact that the connection thru checkpoint was made because i am able to RDP our servers and to  view files etc.

SQL instance name and tfs server are 100% correct , when im connected thru cable in my office both working! also i was able to connect before upgraded to Windows 10

Windows firewall is off! and i did add inbound/outbound rules to allow 1433,8080 ports.

Its happening with all of our servers instances and not just with one! while other users are connected!

I don't know what else to do

Comment: Well, the TFS message does give a few more clues (that it's specifically a name resolution issue) and searching on `windows 10 dns vpn` seems to give a large number of results.

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue. Have you spoken to your networking folks?

Comment: Yes i have, its not a network issue.it has to do something with DNS name resolver or something like that. i managed to connect to tfs but still no luck with SQL Server. i will post answer in the future

Comment: DNS name resolution is a networking issue. This sounds like a problem with your laptop, not with TFS.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1** : You first Run SQL server installation file - setup.exe. Then under the maintenance tab you will find a Repair option. Click on it and proceed,hope it will work.

**Solution 2**: If first solutions not worked then Open SQL Server Manager Console and check it is running and restart it.

**Solution 3** :Go to windows services and check all you SQL server services are running.Disabling SHARED MEMORY (in sql server protocols) can also causes the problem after upgrading to Windows 10 from 7 or 8.1.

Comment: tried the first solution, second is checked and other user are working with SQL Server, shared memory is disabled. and problem is not just with sql but with tfs too. sounds like something with security in my Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried by enabling Shared memory.On Windows 10 you must enable Shared Memory to allow Management Studio to connect to the local SQL database

Comment: Sorry i meant shared memory is enabled. also i'm trying few instances of SQL Servers and all of them are configured correctly. besides tfs is also part of the problem and its not just about SQL Server

Comment: What url you have used while adding a TFS server to Team Explorer?

Comment: i used the http://servername:8080/tfs, now when i try to remove it and insert ip address instead of name then it wont let me add it again.

Comment: Try in this format hope will work http://[tfsserver]:[port]/[vdir]/[projectCollection]